# how to check if a thread is holding a mutex c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix

In my application (C++/Linux) sometimes a thread acquires a mutex(recursive) while getting cancelled.This causes a deadlock as others threads also uses the same mutex and not able to get it.

Now is it possible to check if that thread is locking any mutex.My motive is to clear the manually that the thread is locking and then cancel the thread.

One possible way I can think of is to maintain a counter . Any better approach would be also welcomed  ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean `getting cancelled`?

Comment: in appication threads gets cancelled (pthread_cancel) randomly .. issue occurs when any thread locks a mutex and get cancelled ...not freeing it ..

Comment: @tuban:  Hint:  It's not random.  You have a bug.

Comment: @John : cancellation is done from application ... thats a part of application .. but the issue is it doesnot gurantee mutex release ..

Comment: @tuban: A thread shouldn't get cancelled. A thread should be signaled to exit and perform any resource releasing it needs. Another thread shouldn't kill that thread and pick up the mess itself.

Comment: @Dani ; Agreed .. but anyways is there any better way to identify if there is any mutex held by some threads ..

Comment: @tuban:  So let me get this straight.  You want to be able to kill a thread and the guarantee that it's resources got cleaned up?

Comment: @John: yup .. at least mutexes ...

Comment: If this were possible, the result would be stale by the time it was returned.  I try very hard to not 'cancel', (terminate and destroy wrapper), threads at all during an app run.  It's difficult and dangerous, so I'd rather not do it.

Comment: @tuban:  Not reliably possible.  You need to fix your bug.  The bug, in this case, is the fact that you're killing threads rather than signalling them to die.

Answer (score 4):

Many libraries provide a mechanism similar to Windows' [TryEnterCriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If this returns a signal that indicates the mutex is posessed, then you have your answer.

But you have a much bigger problem than this.  In a properly designed multicode application, you never have deadlocks or race conditions, and you certianly don't have to poke in to another thread manually to manipulate it's state.

Instead of writing some hack, you should fix your bug.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should avoid using `pthread_cancel()` because of problems like this. If you have to use it, you should use [pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cleanup_push.html) to guarantee the mutex is unlocked if the thread is canceled.

There's no way at all to guarantee correct execution if someone's called `pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS)`, so don't do that.

`pthread_cancel()` is very C-ish. Consider using [Boost's thread interruption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.interruption) since you're programming in C++. That'll compose well with scoped locking objects.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, the main problem is the application design.

Hint: In C++ what is the only thing that is guaranteed to be executed in case of a failure (throw)? The destructor.

You have 2 choices:

1. You can use C++11 or boost lock_guard, which encapsulates a normal mutex, but providing exception safety, and are designed to avoid problems like yours. But this means that you need to change the entire application to use C++11 or boost threads, instead of pthread.
2. You can release the mutex in the destructor.

Good luck!